# Changing elements opacity using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the opacity of all buttons after clicking one (except the button that was clicked).

Here is HTML code:

```
<button data-target="Section1" class="metro-button">Button1</button>
<button data-target="Section2" class="metro-button">Button2</button>
<button data-target="Section3" class="metro-button">Button3</button>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$(".metro-button").click(function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("metro-button");
    for(i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
      if ($(this).attr('data-target') != buttons[i].attr('data-target')) {
            buttons[i].animate({"opacity" : 0.3});
       }
    }
});
```

[Demo in JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yC6CD/)

What is the problem ?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you searching through every button when you click on one?  Just use the one you clicked on, `this`.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick with jQuery

```
$(".metro-button").click(function(){
    $(".metro-button").not(this).animate({"opacity" : 0.3});
    $(this).animate({"opacity" : 1});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UUszQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Could be a solution too, depending of your HTML structure:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9p5LX/)

```
$(".metro-button").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }).siblings('.metro-button').animate({
        "opacity": .3
    })
});
```